# Remove web/app_dev.php/ from url

Tags: symfony

I have my application in symfony 2 done.
And now I want to remove the web/app_dev.php/ from the url.

I read about this and after doing this:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

And add .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

After this I can use the url: localhost/test/web/
But it's not exactly my goal. I want to remove the web also.

And after this there's another problem. When I'm using localhost/test/web/ to access the page there's some stylesheet missing, but in app_dev.php everything looks good.

My question is, How can I remove the /web/ from the url?
And how can I have the stylesheet missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Apache/mod_rewrite configuration

To remove the `/web` part you can set `RewriteBase` additionally

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /web/
    ...
```

... or set your `DocumentRoot` directly to the `web` folder in your apache `VirtualHost` configuration.

## stylesheet issue

The missing stylesheet in the `prod` environment can be resolved by invoking the `assets:install` command.

In the `dev` symfony will serve the files directly from the bundle's `Resources/public` folders because the default `config_dev.yml` contains `assetic.use_controller: true`.

The default production configuration has `assetic.use_controller: false` for performance reasons. Assets will not be recompiled and served through symfony on every request.

Now the assets in a bundle's `Resource` folder are not accessible until they are being moved/symlinked to the `web` folder where your webserver can find them which the `assets:install` and `assetic:dump` commands do.

Comment: /web problem solved
but now cant fix the stylesheet, I run the command php app/console assets:install --env=prod and then i clean the cache and still the same issue. I'm using cssless to generate this stylesheets

Comment: Please open a separate question for the stylesheet issue and provide more information. Which files don't get loaded? Only some or all? Where do your files come from (i.e. Bundle/Resources/public )? How do you include them in your template ( i.e. using `{{ asset(..) }}` or `{% stylesheets .. }` ? What URL gets generated and returns the 404 error (see firebug/devtools network panel)? Include your assetic configuration for the prod environment aswell please.

Comment: I fixed everything, the .htaccess and the missing pictures, but now theres just the icons dont show! I'm using a template with bootstrap icons, and they dont show

Answer (score 4):

To remove the web you simply have to modify your apache configuration to make web as root directory.

```
    DocumentRoot /yourpath/www/web
    <Directory /youpath/www/web/>
```

Exemple of Apache Virtual Host Complete configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /yourpath/www/web

    <Directory /yourpath/www/web>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from All

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/your_site.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/your_site.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In production you should remove `app_dev.php` and set as root directory symfony web folder

Note: I don't add `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>` because if you don't have it you want apache to inform you that you are missing this module.