# Symfony2 - How can I remove 'web/app_dev.php/' from my url?

Tags: php, symfony

How can I remove 'web/app_dev.php/' from my url when I want my symfony website to go live?

This is the default url during development,

```
http://{localhost}/my-symfony-2/web/app_dev.php/hello/World
```

So when I go live, I would like to be able to use this url to access my symfony website,

```
http://my-symfony-2.com/hello/World
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove "web/app\_dev.php" from Symfony2 URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669458/how-to-remove-web-app-dev-php-from-symfony2-urls)

Comment: I came across that one but it has no accepted answer. how can i know it is the correct answer then?

Comment: did you **try** any of provided solutions?

Comment: I tried with this one `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug` but nothing has changed.

Comment: try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259519/remove-web-app-dev-php-from-url and try to google "symfony2 remove app_dev.php from url" - you will get 4 answers from stackoverflow

Comment: You should edit the question to specify what you have tried and the results you obtained. That would save time to people trying things that you know have failed already

Comment: it says `And add .htaccess:` - where should I add it then? I added to my symfony root directory then I get an `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: If you use Apache you can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460935/how-to-set-the-web-root-and-hide-app-php-and-app-dev-php-in-localhost-using-xamp)

Comment: yes on my localhost, i'm on Apache, but on the live server, how can I change anything on the hosting server?? I mean I cannot change `DocumentRoot` this bit on the live server, can I?

Comment: @oasis if you've access to the web root you can use these directives (only those which concern the removing a part of the url) on an .htaccess file also for the production site.

Comment: @gp_sflover you mean I should add an .htaccess? if so, where should I add it? what should i put in the .htaccess?

Comment: @oasis yes you need to add an .htaccess file. Now I can't, but I will write the answer later if someone doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide `app.php` you need to:

1. having access at least to the web root of your site. Usually on the control panel of your web hosting space you can find from which you can upload your files (or if you have the access credentials you can install and use a Free FTP client like [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)).
2. checking if you have the `mod_rewrite` module installed and enabled in Apache looking the `phpinfo()` under "apache2handler" ---> "Loaded Modules" directory (you should have that possibility directly through the control panel).

After these checks you have to:

**NOTE**: Symfony2 already comes with an `.htaccess` file stored in the default web directory but if you don't know what are you doing it's better to replace the directives containet within the "IfModule mod_rewrite.c" with those shown below.

1. Use the native Symfony2 `.htaccess` or create a new one file with the `.htaccess` extension and copy/paste inside these directives to hide `app.php` in production (not on localhost):

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On  
       RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$  
       RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]
       RewriteRule .? - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
       RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]    
       RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app.php [L]
   </IfModule>

   # and from the symfony's original
   <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
       <IfModule mod_alias.c>
           # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
           # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
           # and the generated links can still be used.
       RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
           # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
       </IfModule>
   </IfModule>
   ```

   To apply the modifications you need to restart Apache (also this is usually did on the control panel of your web space).

Googling a bit you can find tons of examples and tutorials but to start to learn take a look at this simple [.htaccess guide with many useful infos and examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) and the [Official URL Rewriting Guide (Apache2.4)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/). If you encounter some problem update your post adding all related infos otherwise you can make another question here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the deployment server, from terminal you can use:
`php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` and this will clear the prod cache and you will be able to use the standard route.

But if you are deploying the application on hosting where you haven't access to terminal, need to find the `app/cache/*` and `app/logs/*` and remove their content and after add the proper rights (766|777) for the folders.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i can't do command lines on the hosting server. I don't understand this bit - `need to find the app/cache/* and app/logs/* and remove their content and after add the proper rights (766|777) for the folders.`

Comment: after you copy all the code on the server, browse to folder `app/cache/` and `app/logs` remove all the content in the folders, add read + write rights for the folders