# Forwarding Symfony website to it's main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, web-hosting, symfony-2.3

The whole project is  accessible at `mysite.com/projectfolder/web/web_dev.php`   but how would I point it to mysite.com. I have use digitalocean vps to host this site.

What  should I change in `.htaccess` file

my current settings are:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.comn$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/projectfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$/app_dev.php [L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - How can I remove 'web/app\_dev.php/' from my url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145359/symfony2-how-can-i-remove-web-app-dev-php-from-my-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not change the .htaccess file. You need to configure the Nginx or the Apache file instead.

Here is a good cookbook : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-application-to-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @HarshShah you can validate the answer then ;)