# How to remove "web" in url on Symfony2

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I want to remove "web" in URL. For example, I request such as the bottom URL.

```
http://localhost/symfony/web/mypage
```

But, I want to request such as the bottom URL.

```
http://localhost/symfony/mypage
```

So, I create .htaccess in document root and write settings.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^symfony/(.*)$ symfony/web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And I got 404 error. This error messges appear in app/log/prod.log.

> [2015-04-27 15:19:09] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /symfony/mypage/"" at
>   /home/foobar/public_html/symfony/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1885
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code:
>   0): No route found for \"GET /symfony/mypage/\" at
>   /home/foobar/public_html/symfony/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1885,
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code:
>   0):  at
>   /home/foobar/public_html/symfony/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:781)"}
>   []

How to remove "web" in url on Symfony2 ?

Comment: Just install symfony on top of document root, then rename `web` to `symfony`.

Comment: see  [Remove web/app_dev.php/ from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259519/remove-web-app-dev-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

You should configure a virtual host that point to /web directory if you use symfony 2.6 you should not have this kind of probleme because it cames with it's own server that point to the web directory by default.